# Addition and "subtraction" of polytopes

Tags: geometry, polytopes

Suppose $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ are polytopes. Suppose also that I know that there exists a polytope $\mathcal{X}$ such that $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{B}$.

> Is $\mathcal{X}$ defined uniquely? (How about uniquely "up to translation"?)

This means that the idea of "subtraction", as the opposite of addition, makes sense. (I know that there is a subtraction defined for polytopes, but I am having some trouble connecting it to the above.)

---

The solution to my question follows from the "duplication" link as if $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{Y}=\mathcal{B}$ then $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{Y}$, and hence $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}$ as required.

Comment: @Ethan It is not clear to me that your link answers my question. If $\mathcal{P}+\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{Q}+\mathcal{R}\Rightarrow \mathcal{P}=\mathcal{Q}$, then how should I pick $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ here?!?

Comment: @Ethan Never mind; I understand now. Thanks.